# How to install JLink in Docker's ubuntu?

Tags: image, docker, ubuntu, dockerhub

I want to install JLink in my docker's ubuntu container. I downloaded JLink_Linux_V680_x86_64.deb and copied it from host OS to ubuntu container and tried to run

**apt-get install ./JLink_Linux_V680_x86_64.deb**

But couldn't install it.
How can I install JLink in the ubuntu container?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below command.

`sudo docker cp JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb <container_id>:/home/JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb`

`ls /home/`

`dpkg -i /home/JLink_Linux_V647f_x86_64.deb`

Check [this](https://wiki.segger.com/J-Link_Docker_Container) for more details